# In the Kafka Java API, will ConsumerGroupDescription.state() have updated results?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have fetched a `ConsumerGroupDescription` using `org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin`.  Will I get the latest state when calling `state()`, or do I need to fetch the `ConsumerGroupDescription` again?

```
val consumerGroup: ConsumerGroupDescription = admin
    .describeConsumerGroups(listOf(groupId), DescribeConsumerGroupsOptions().timeoutMs(1000))
    .describedGroups()
    .map { (_, description) -> description.get() }
    .first()

for (i in 0..10) {
    val state = consumerGroup.state()
    if (state == ConsumerGroupState.DEAD || state == ConsumerGroupState.EMPTY) break
    log.info("Consumer group $groupId is in state $state, waiting for it to become DEAD or EMPTY")
    Thread.sleep(2000)
}
```